# gradle get khttp timout

Tags: gradle, build, dependencies

Received this exception when trying to build a java project via Gradle then got timeout error. Other dependencies are downloaded correctly, but not khttp one. I can download the khttp pom file using browser. Added root certificate to Java and Intellij. Thanks in advance

> project : > org.springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin:org.springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin.gradle.plugin:1.3.2 > org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-gradle-plugin:1.3.2
> Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve khttp:khttp:1.0.0.
> Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/khttp/khttp/1.0.0/khttp-1.0.0.pom'.